# Change logo location

Tags: css

I need to change my logo location. I've tried any code i know from css but still cant change the location.
I want the logo to be at the same height of my menu.
Need your help please!

My website is : http://ktiniatreio-keratea.gr/

Comment: Add display: inline-block; to your .navbar-header class

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your instant response and help!

Answer (score 1):

**Add to css**

```
.navbar-header{
    display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your instant response and help!

Comment: @AggelosGerontaris really appricate if you mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

Put the:

```
<div class="main-navigation navbar-collapse collapse">
```

inside the `class="navbar-header"`.

[image: preview]

Your final code should look like:

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
  <a href="http://ktiniatreio-keratea.gr/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="290" height="70" src="https://i2.wp.com/ktiniatreio-keratea.gr/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/cropped-logo_pet-2.png?fit=290%2C70" class="custom-logo" alt="Κτηνιατρικό Κέντρο : Λυγιάς – Νεοφύτου"></a>
  <div class="main-navigation navbar-collapse collapse">
    <div id="mega-menu-wrap-primary" class="mega-menu-wrap">
      <div class="mega-menu-toggle" tabindex="0">
        <div class="mega-toggle-blocks-left">
          <div class="mega-toggle-block mega-menu-toggle-block mega-toggle-block-1" id="mega-toggle-block-1"><span class="mega-toggle-label"><span class="mega-toggle-label-closed">MENU</span><span class="mega-toggle-label-open">MENU</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mega-toggle-blocks-center"></div>
        <div class="mega-toggle-blocks-right">
          <div class="mega-toggle-block mega-menu-toggle-block mega-toggle-block-2" id="mega-toggle-block-2"><span class="mega-toggle-label"><span class="mega-toggle-label-closed">MENU</span><span class="mega-toggle-label-open">MENU</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul id="mega-menu-primary" class="mega-menu max-mega-menu mega-menu-horizontal">
        <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-menu-item-home mega-current-menu-item mega-page_item mega-page-item-150 mega-current_page_item mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-157" id="mega-menu-item-157"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://ktiniatreio-keratea.gr/" tabindex="0">Αρχική</a></li>
        <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-241" id="mega-menu-item-241"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://ktiniatreio-keratea.gr/%ce%b9%ce%b1%cf%84%cf%81%ce%b5%ce%b9%ce%b1/" tabindex="0">Τα Ιατρεία</a></li>
        <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-242" id="mega-menu-item-242"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://ktiniatreio-keratea.gr/%cf%85%cf%80%ce%b7%cf%81%ce%b5%cf%83%ce%b9%ce%b5%cf%82/" tabindex="0">Υπηρεσίες</a></li>
        <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-521" id="mega-menu-item-521"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://ktiniatreio-keratea.gr/team/" tabindex="0">Προσωπικό</a></li>
        <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-244" id="mega-menu-item-244"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://ktiniatreio-keratea.gr/contact/" tabindex="0">Επικοινωνία</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your instant response and help!

Answer (score 0):

add `display: inline;` to your `navbar-header`

e.g.

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="
    display: inline;
">
```

Answer (score 0):

in your class container

```
.container{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
}
```

and

```
.main-navigation{
margin:auto;}
```

[image]

Comment: You're css master !